# jhipster recreate database tables

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-data, jhipster, liquibase

using jhipster I have created `Angular` based **Monolith** application (`MySQL`) and loaded `jdl` file, everything is working fine. But by mistake I have dropped MySQL database schema. Now I have recreated the database schema, but now when I run `./mvnw`, it is not creating the database tables and entries any more even the login and authentication tables were also not created? Is there settings change I need to make to recreate the database all the database tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase does not create the schema, it creates tables, indexes, ... but only in a pre-existing database/schema. You must re-create your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can create schema from liquibase, but not a database, so you  must just create database, and for schema you can use this:

```
<sql> CREATE SCHEMA yourSchema </sql>
```